# An Ordinary Differential Equation with time varying coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ and $B$ be complex numbers, let $\beta_1$ be real and $\beta_2=2$. Consider a following Ordinary Differential Equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{ d^2 r_t}{ d t^2} + \left(\frac{A}{t^{\beta_1}} + \frac{B}{t^{\beta_2}}\right) r_t = 0
\end{equation}
By substituting for $t^{2 - \frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}{2}}$ and using the power series method I have shown that the fundamental solutions to this equation are:
\begin{equation}
r_t = \sqrt{t} J_{\pm \frac{\sqrt{1-4 B}}{-2 + \beta_1}} \left[\frac{2 \sqrt{A} t^{1-\frac{\beta_1}{2}}}{-2+\beta_1}\right]
\end{equation}
Here $J_\beta$ is the Bessel function.
Unfortunately the power series method fails in case of $\beta_2 \neq 2$ . Is there a different method for finding the solution in case $\beta_2 \neq 2$.